# How to send base64 string to server using volley

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-volley

I'm using volley library in android to call our server when try to send base64 encoded image to server the request fail but when remove the encoded string the request success without any issue.
I use the following code to encode my image

```
  public static String imgToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
try {
  out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
  out.flush();
  out.close();
  byte[] imgBytes = out.toByteArray();
  return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
} catch (Exception e) {
  return null;
} finally {
  try {
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

and send request using volley with the following

```
public void sendDataToServer(final ApiResponse.Listener<JSONObject> listener, final ApiResponse.ErrorListener errorListener, String image) {
String url = String.format(ASK, image);
url = URLEncoder.encode(url);
JsonRequest sendRequest = new JsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            listener.onResponse(response);
          }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    if (error != null) {
      if (error.networkResponse != null) {
        errorListener.onErrorResponse(error.networkResponse.statusCode, null);
      } else {
        errorListener.onErrorResponse(500, null);
      }
    }
  }
});
RequestPipeline.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(sendRequest);
```

}

Comment: Provide more details. How exactly does request fail? Bad server respones? Network issue? Something else? Also what is `JsonEmptyResponseRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your code it looks like you try to pass whole encoded image as a part of URL. Obviously this fail because servers typically don't support URL longer than a few thousand of symbols. To pass long data to the server you should use body of the POST. I don't know what your `JsonEmptyResponseRequest` class is and what format the server expects (how `ASK` is specified). Just to give you an idea how this might be implemented

```
StringRequest sendRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener ...,
        new Response.ErrorListener...){

  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put(IMAGE_PARAM_NAME, image);
      return params;
  }
};
```

In real life you probably want to create your own sub-class of `Request<T>` and pass image there as a constructor parameter and hide exactly details of what server expects inside that class. Note that `JsonRequest` overrides `getBody` and `getBodyContentType` to use JSON so this will not work with `JsonRequest` subclass.

Comment: thanks for your time, JsonEmptyResponseRequest  i use it to handle my requests to server it my customized class and ASK is my url to format it with my parameter. I will try your idea now

Comment: @iosamammohamed When I say "I don't know what your such and such" I mean not that I don't get general idea but that I don't know specific details you didn't mention in your question and they are important to provide correct answer